# How to set up proxy settings for chrome driver webdriver samper in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I am trying to run Jmeter Webdriver script in Blazemeter. The browser is getting launched but subsequent requests are failing. Further investigation it was identified that the chrome driver is not able to launch the expected URL due to proxy requirements.

I tried to use proxy settings in Jmeter Set Up Thread Group using JSR223 sampler.
Below is the code for the same.

With this I am getting "The driver is not executable error" in Blazemeter.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHTTPProxy("xyz.net:1234");
proxy.SslProxy("xyz.net:1234");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability ("proxy", proxy);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver", "chromedriver");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe it's better to address this form of questions to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)
2. `The driver is not executable` error doesn't have anything in common with proxies, you need to amend your `chromedriver` [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) to allow its execution)

Take the following steps:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to your test plan
2. Add [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to your Thread Group
3. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
4. That's it, you should be able to launch the browser now

Comment: I have used the above approach initially. The browser was launching but the calls to launch the url and subsequent requests were failing. Hence I was asked to use proxy to launch chrome due to the limitation of not able to set the proxy at container level. I have posted the question here because I was thinking the way I am setting proxy from code is not right. Appreciate your help on this.